An affair between a rich man's wife and a blonde boy
From what I remember, some rich man leaves his wife (which is younger, around 40 may be?) for a few days, and then a young blonde boy comes in and has a romance with her.
I remember the film had lots of “basic cool stuff”: he wears RayBan, uses MacBook (he goes to university), they both drive an old vintage red car at some point (I'm not 100% sure about this), he wears leather jackets, they kiss in a tower of an old building, etc.
IIRC, in the end the husband returns, and the young boy (around 25 years) and him (around 60) somehow meet in his boat.
I even think the husband knows, because someone takes photos of them. But I might be mixing films.
I don't remember most of it, and I saw the name Under the Tuscan sun in the TV so I thought that was the name, but now checking it seems that I mixed ideas and that should've been playing in another channel :(
Any ideas?

Do you have an approximate year the film was made? When did you see the film?

Nope, but the metal MacBooks appear there, so might be newer than 2008.

It's a long shot but this could be "The Door in the Floor" (2004):
Ted (Jeff Bridges) and Marion (Kim Basinger) temporarily separate, each alternately living in the house and in a rented apartment in town. Ted hires Eddie O'Hare (Jon Foster) to work as his summer assistant and driver, since his own license was suspended for drunk driving. An aspiring writer, Eddie admires Ted, but he soon discovers the older man is a self-absorbed womanizer with an erratic work schedule that leaves the young assistant to fill his time as best he can. Eddie and Marion soon engage in a sexual relationship, which seems not to bother Ted, who is enjoying trysts of his own with local resident Evelyn Vaughn (Mimi Rogers) --Wikipedia entry


No it wasn't. It is more recent and probably of serie B (no Jeff Bridges could appear in such film :D).

@Manuel Jeff Bridges has appeared in a movie far worse than a B movie, it was called R.I.P.D. :)

@steelerfan I thought two or three just at the moment I wrote the comment.

@Manuel...sorry, I could not resist the R.I.P.D. comment :)
